# How to add a new hugo static page?

Tags: hugo

From the "getting started" section it seems this should work, but it doesn't.

```
hugo new site my-site
hugo new privacy.md
hugo server --watch --includeDrafts

curl -L localhost:1313/privacy/index.html
# 404 page not found
curl -L localhost:1313/privacy.html
# 404 page not found
curl -L localhost:1313/privacy/
# 404 page not found
```

How can I add a new page?

Comment: From what I understand: create it like any other post with the exception that it it should be in the `content` directory. i.e. don't put it inside the `content/posts` directory

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just tested OK with this on Hugo 0.13:

```sh
hugo new site my-site
cd my-site
hugo new privacy.md
hugo server -w -D
curl -L localhost:1313/privacy/
```

Note: You have to either use a theme or provide your own layout template to get something more than a blank page. And of course, some Markdown in privacy.md would also make it even nicer.

See http://gohugo.io/overview/introduction for up-to-date documentation.

Comment: Why do you need the -w -d?

Comment: With hugo 0.69.0, that's not working any longer for me.

`% curl -L localhost:1313/privacy/`:  `404 page not found`

Comment: Make sure to set draft: 'false' for the page to show up

Comment: If you're seeing a `404 page not found` make sure you set `type: page` and have a `single.html` layout as explained in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46216333/why-my-single-page-in-hugo-returns-a-404-http-error

Comment: @neric you don't need to set `draft: false` if you use the -D flag on the `hugo server`, as this enables rendering of drafts as well I believe

Comment: Do you have to use `hugo new`? What if I already have a file? Do I really have to move it out of the way to use `hugo new` and then move it back?

Answer (score 46):

This is the best tutorial how to create static "landing pages" on Hugo: https://discuss.gohugo.io/t/creating-static-content-that-uses-partials/265/19?u=royston

Basically, you create .md in `/content/` with `type: "page"` in front matter, then create custom layout for it, for example `layout: "simple-static"` in front matter, then create the layout template in `themes/<name>/layouts/page/`, for example, `simple-static.html`. Then, use all partials as usual, and call content from original .md file using `{{ .Content }}`.

All my static (landing) pages are using this method.

By the way, I'm not using `hugo new`, I just clone .md file or copy a template into `/content/` and open it using my *iA Writer* text editor. But I'm not using Hugo `server` either, adapted [npm-build-boilerplate](https://github.com/damonbauer/npm-build-boilerplate) is running the server and builds.

Comment: imo the process is bit complicated. But thanks u showed a direction ! =)

Comment: This should have been the right answer and also aligns with the documentation of Hugo as on 2020.

Comment: THIS WORKS, I just checked. I spent a shameful amount of time on this.

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar requirement, to add static page (`aboutus` in this case). Following steps did the trick,

- Created an empty file `content/aboutus/_index.md`
- Created aboutus.html page `layouts/section/aboutus.html`

Answer (score 4):

Make you have some default frontmatter set in `archetypes/default.md`

```
# archetypes/default.md
+++
title: "{{ replace .Name "-" " " | title }}"
date: {{ .Date }}
draft: true
+++
```

And the single layout in `layouts/_default/single.html` to render some variable or content

```
# tags to render markdown content
<h1>{{ .Title }}</h1>
<p>{{ .Content }}</p>
<span>{{ .Params.date }}</span>
```

Now type `hugo new privacy.md` which will create a new page on the following directory in `content/privacy.md`

Answer (score 3):

Take "About" as example:

```sh
# will create content/about.md
hugo new about.md
```

Edit about.md and add the last 2 lines, the metadata/front matter looks like:

```
title: "About"
date: 2019-03-26
menu: "main"
weight: 50
```

That should work.

Comment: This got the link in menu. But I could see it as post as well in home page. Any way to remove that?

Comment: Do you have to use `hugo new`? What if I already have a file? Do I really have to move it out of the way to use `hugo new` and then move it back?