# Why my single page in Hugo returns a 404 HTTP error?

Tags: hugo

I am trying to create a site with [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/), but I don't get how to add a single page to my website (posts are working fine).

Starting from a fresh install (*v.0.27 64x* for *windows*) and running the following command from my terminal:

```
> hugo new site soexample
> cd soexample
> git clone https://github.com/parsiya/Hugo-Octopress.git themes\octopress
> hugo new about.md
> echo "Please display me" >> content\about.md
> hugo serve -D -t octopress
```

I can see that my draft page is rendered from the output of the last command:

```
...
Built site for language en:
1 of 1 draft rendered
...
```

but when I try to access either `http://localhost:1313/about/` or `http://localhost:1313/about.html`, the server (not the browser) returns a white page with:

```
404 page not found
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Should I instead put my page in a section ?
That is to say move `soexample\content\about.md` to `soexample\content\about\_index.md` ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem seems to come from the selected default theme that do not render [single page](https://gohugo.io/themes/creating/#single-content) outside of posts [section](https://gohugo.io/content-management/sections/). Themes can be a tricky point for beginners as hugo isn't shipped with default one and no official theme is recommended or supported (so beginners may have to choose randomly).

So the following commands worked for me:

```
> hugo new site soexample
> cd soexample
> git clone https://github.com/spf13/hyde.git themes\hyde
> hugo new about.md
> echo "Please display me" >> content\about.md
> hugo serve -D -t hyde
```

The page `http://localhost:1313/about/` is correctly rendered.

Comment: Is there a standard way to edit a theme so that it does render single pages outside post sections?

Comment: Depends what you mean by _standard_: you can add a `single.html` file inside your `layout\default`folder. It will override any layout from your theme to render single files with this layout.
The only thing is that the coupling with the theme layouts can be tricky to get rid of.
The minimal content you want in your `single.html` file is `{{.Content}}`, but you will surely want other elements (header, footer) that can be dependent of your current theme.

Comment: Note that this will not render your home page (`content/_index.md`), which looks for `layout/index.html`. I worked around this by creating a symlink.

Comment: note that you need to change `draft: true` to `draft: false` in the front matter in order for the page to render correctly

Comment: [do not forget the frontmatter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46551772/1705829) in about.md.

Answer (score 13):

In order to render standalone pages in Hugo you need to set the type to page and make sure you have a 'single' template in your layouts.

In the `about.md` front-matter set `type = "page"`. In the layouts folder under `_default` folder make sure you have a `single.html` file.

That's it, the `/about` page now should render properly.

Comment: I have been searching for the answer for this in Hugo's official documentation for hours.

Comment: The single template was exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: `type = "page"` changed to `type: page` in frontmatter, my version is 0.121

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate, [How to add a new hugo static page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28569458/how-to-add-a-new-hugo-static-page?rq=1)

I already answer in that question, copy pasting here also.

I had a similar requirement, to add static page (`aboutus` in this case). Following steps did the trick,

- Created an empty file `content/aboutus/_index.md`
- Created aboutus.html page `layouts/section/aboutus.html`

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled on here, it was drafts, but in my case the solution had an interesting wrinkle:

```
about/_index.md  (draft)
about/other.md  (not a draft)
```

Hugo ignores other.md when not building drafts, regardless of other.mds draft state. I'll leave it to the reader to decide if this is a bug or a feature.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the configuration file hugo.toml,Change baseURL to "/"

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem could be related to draft.

By default, the newly created content has `draft: true`, and hugo will exclude draft files by default.

You can change it to `draft: false` or use `--buildDrafts` option.

Comment: Actually the opposite, newly created content has `draft: true`.