# Hugo Site hosted in GitHub Pages. Main page shows ok but the Blog goes to 404

Tags: github-pages, hugo

I have a site hosted on GitHub Pages:
https://mcbridebr.github.io/mysite-hugo/

I have it setup to publish to pages from the docs/ directory in the master branch.  When I run `hugo` it will publish to docs/.

I can bring up the home page just fine.  But when I click on Blog it goes to 404.  I have a blog post that is blank under content/post/. If I run this locally and access it with localhost:1313 the BLOG link works.  I am not sure what is happening here, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Source Repo:  https://github.com/mcbridebr/mysite-hugo

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46216333/why-my-single-page-in-hugo-returns-a-404-http-error

Comment: Thanks for that link.  I actually came across it before posting here.  Not quite the same issue I think though.

Answer (score 0):

I had to go back and add additional layout index.html files to accommodate for the blog section.