# How to build static html pages in Hugo and define layout template to format pages?

Tags: python, html, flask, vue.js, hugo

My goal is to convert an existing web site from Python+Flask and Angular(js) to static pages constructed by Hugo with dynamic content displayed by Vue.js. My first steps are to convert the existing dynamically composed (by flask) pages into statically composed pages.

I have been able to construct the main landing page and separate the pages into parts/sections. The main page renders fine, but I am now trying to build the additional pages.

I have templates for the headers, footers, and interesting scripts defined in layouts/partials/ and I want to construct appropriate layout templates for the rest of the pages.

I have stored the desired content pages for additional (child) pages into the content/ directory. But when I read the documentation, it isn't clear how to wrap these pages in the header+footer using appropriate layouts/ templates.

Specifics:
I have pages A.html, B.html, and C.html stored in content/
I have an index page layout template that composes an index body html and that all works well.
But how would I provide layouts/ templates for each of A, B, and C that provide appropriate headers+footers, so that the parent page can link to those pages using ".BaseURL/A", ".BaseURL/B", ".BaseURL/C"?

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28569458/how-to-add-a-new-hugo-static-page) provides details on how to create the page in Hugo (which I have done). But my question is about layout & formatting that page (fragment).

Comment: This may be more about Hugo configuration than programming, but it may be a simple configuration or location error.

Comment: Hi, your question is about creating general layout for all pages content (A,B,C) or specific layout for A, specific for B and specific for C?